# Mass Role Assigner Command for a Discord.js Bot

Tags: javascript, discord, bots, discord.js

I've been working on a discord bot in discord.js that assigns a role to the people mentioned in this framework:

${prefix}assignrole ${role} ${user1} ${user2} ${user3} ...

I have figured out a way to assign the role to one person but I can't find a way to assign it to many people. Heres my code:

```js
if(command === "assignrole"){
  if(!message.member.roles.some(r=>["Defenestration Administration", "Moderator", "Admin", "Administrator/Creator"].includes(r.name)) )
      return message.reply("Sorry, you don't have permissions to use this!");
  var role = message.mentions.roles.first();
  var roleId = message.mentions.roles.first().id

  message.mentions.members.first().addRole(roleId)

  if(!role) {
    return message.channel.send("Wrong Input, Must Type a Valid Role After the Command!")
  }
  
}
```

Can someone help me by showing me a way to assign multiple users a role.

Any answers or help are appreciated, thanks :)

-Joshua

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`message.mentions.members` is a collection. It contains all the members you mentioned in the message. You can loop through the aforementioned collection and add the role.

---

```js
if (command === "assignrole") {
    const Role = message.mentions.roles.first();

    message.mentions.members.forEach(member => {
        member.roles.add(Role).catch(e => console.error(e));
    });

    message.channel.send(`Added role ${Role.name} to ${message.mentions.members.map(member => member.user.tag).join(", ")}.`);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but  I had to fix member.roles.add to member.addRole so I could actually run the bot as it showed an error and when I run the command it only assigns the role to only one of the two mentioned members (the last one). But it works when it is more than two and doesn't when its 2 or 1 roles mentioned. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Jakye, you can also use a for loop to avoid rate limit with an async system.

```js
client.on("message", async message => {

  let membersArray = message.mentions.members.array();

  for(var guildMemberId in membersArray) {
    await membersArray[guildMemberId].roles.add(message.mentions.roles.first());
  }

  message.channel.send("All members have received the role " + message.mentions.roles.first().name + ".");
}
```